# get JsonArray int values inside a JsonArray in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a json file with the next estructure:

```
    [
{
    "id": 3,
    "numbers": [0,1,5,3,4]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "numbers": [3,7]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "numbers": []
}]
```

And i get access to the general array and the tag "id", but when i want to access to the array surrounded by the tag "numbers" i can't get the inside values, this is my Java code

```
    JsonArray arr = parser.parse(content).getAsJsonArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        JsonObject object= arr .get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        String id= object.get("id").getAsString();
        JsonArray numbarr = objeto.get("numbers").getAsJsonArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < numbarr.size(); j++) {
            JsonObject object2 = numbarr.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

        }
    }
```

how i can access to the values of the inside array and save them? The numbers can be any int value or an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Close.

```
JsonArray arr = new JsonParser().parse(content).getAsJsonArray();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject object = arr.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    String id = object.get("id").getAsString();
    JsonArray numbarr = object.get("numbers").getAsJsonArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < numbarr.size(); j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", numbarr.get(j).getAsInt());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```